# Loading a relation in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Below is my pig script: In the first step I am loading data into temp. Here temp will have filename(abc.txt) not the data. So DUMP temp will print abc.txt
I want to load the data from the file abc.txt. Any help as I am getting error.

```
temp = LOAD '/usr/filename.txt' using PigStorage(';');
DUMP temp;
info = LOAD '$temp' from PigStorage(';');
```

Comment: can you tell us more about your data ?

Comment: can you Edit your question with some sample data and what you get when dump as output. ?

Comment: Welcome to SO community. Please spend sometime on [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). then improve your question.

Comment: Be more specific and clear.

Comment: In the above script. temp has a file name(abc.txt). This file name(abc.txt) will keep changing and I need to get the file name dynamically everytime I invoke the script and load the data from the file name. so when I give  info = LOAD '$temp' from PigStorage(';), it's giving an error

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable to read your data before load command.
Example:

```
%declare temp `bash -c "hdfs dfs -cat /usr/filename.txt"`;
info = LOAD '$temp' USING PigStorage(';');
```